# How do I physically protect solar panels from snapping when dropped?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, aerospace-engineering, photovoltaics

I am creating a system that I drop from 20m to the ground and I want it to be solar powered. Weight is an issue so I am trying to minimise it as much as I can. How can I ensure that the solar panels remain intact and don't break upon being dropped if they are attached to this system? I was thinking foam insulating to both hold it in place and absorb the force, but are there any other suggestions?

Comment: 20m is a substantial drop to protect against.  Your question would be improved if you provided more details about what the package is as well as why it is being used this way.  I would imagine that controlling for rotation while falling would also be a concern.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsnyl8llfH4

Comment: Use the flexble solar panels...